# kubernetes mariadb-galera cluster - bitnami helm chart - Readiness probe failed

Tags: database, kubernetes, cluster, mariadb, galera

I am trying to setup a mariadb-galera cluster through the bitnami helm chart in my kubernetes cluster (1 master, 3 nodes). I have modified the *myvalues.yaml* to include <s>an `existingClaim: dbstorage` and</s> the `storageClass: "nfs-storage"`. The image repository is *10.5.9-debian-10-r52*, I added a root password <s>and outcommented the `accessModes:` as well as the *size* as that was defined in the existing persistence volume claim</s>. I did not define anything in the section db: and left that as the defaults. I also did not define anything under the `galera.mariabackup` section like password and left the defaults.

As soon as I run the helm chart with `helm install helm install mariadb-galera-cluster -f mariadb-galera.values.yaml bitnami/mariadb-galera --namespace database` and describe the pod I get the error message

```
Readiness probe failed: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' 
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

When checking the container for that mysql.sock it is true, that it is not available in that location.

I am using a NFS provisioner to provision the persistent storage which works fine. On my nfs server I can see the directory being created and data being stored in it. It is a NFS3 directory that is used by the container.

When I access the container and try to run the scrips "run.sh" or "entrypoint.sh" in the folder `/opt/bitnami/scripts/mariadb-galera` I am getting an error `The mariadb configuration file '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf' is not writable or does not exist. Configurations based on environment variables will not be applied for this file.` but the file is right in the folder where it should be.
All components, like the stateful set are created and started properly as I can tell just the container, in my case it was obviously called mariadb-galera-cluster-0, is not finishing starting up because of the socket it can't find.

Version of Helm:

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.4", GitCommit:"1b5edb69df3d3a08df77c9902dc17af864ff05d1", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.15.11"}
```

Version of Kubernetes

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:25:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**version of the values.yaml file**

```
## Please, note that this will override the image parameters, including dependencies, configured to use the global v$
## Current available global Docker image parameters: imageRegistry and imagePullSecrets
##
# global:
#   imageRegistry: myRegistryName
#   imagePullSecrets:
#     - myRegistryKeySecretName
#   storageClass: myStorageClass

## Bitnami MariaDB Galera image
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mariadb-galera/tags/
##
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/mariadb-galera
  tag: 10.5.9-debian-10-r52
  ## Specify a imagePullPolicy
  ## Defaults to 'Always' if image tag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
  ##
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
  ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
  ##
  # pullSecrets:
  #   - myRegistryKeySecretName

  ## Set to true if you would like to see extra information on logs
  ##
  debug: false

## String to partially override common.names.fullname template (will maintain the release name)
##
# nameOverride:

## String to fully override common.names.fullname template
##
# fullnameOverride:

## Use an alternate scheduler, e.g. "stork".
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
# schedulerName:

## Specifies the Kubernetes Cluster's Domain Name.
##
clusterDomain: cluster.local

## StatefulSet controller supports relax its ordering guarantees while preserving its uniqueness and identity guaran$
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#pod-management-policy
##
podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady

## Deployment pod host aliases
## https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/
hostAliases: []

## MariaDB Gallera K8s svc properties
##
service:
  ## Kubernetes service type and port number
  ##
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 3306
  # clusterIP: None

  ## Specify the nodePort value for the LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport
  ##
  # nodePort: 30001

  ## Specify the externalIP value ClusterIP service type.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips
  ##
  # externalIPs: []

  ## Set the LoadBalancer service type to internal only.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer
  ##
  # loadBalancerIP:

  ## Load Balancer sources
  ## https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-$
  ##
  # loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  # - 10.10.10.0/24

  ## Provide any additional annotations which may be required. This can be used to
  ## set the LoadBalancer service type to internal only.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer
  ##
  annotations: {}

  ## Headless service properties
  ##
  headless:
    ## Additional annotations for headless service.
    ## Can be useful in case peer-finder is used in a sidecar,
    ## e.g.: service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints="true"
    ##
    annotations: {}

## Pods Service Account
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/
##
serviceAccount:
  ## Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  ##
  create: false
  ## The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  ## If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the common.names.fullname template
  ##
  name: ""

## An array to add extra environment variables
## For example:
## extraEnvVars:
##  - name: TZ
##    value: "Europe/Paris"
##
extraEnvVars:

## ConfigMap with extra env vars:
##
extraEnvVarsCM:

## Secret with extra env vars:
##
extraEnvVarsSecret:

## Role Based Access
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/
##
rbac:
  ## Specifies whether RBAC rules should be created
  ##
  create: false

## Pod Security Context
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/
##
securityContext:
  enabled: true
  fsGroup: 1001
  runAsUser: 1001

## Database credentials for root (admin) user
##
rootUser:
  ## MariaDB admin user
  ##
  user: root
  ## MariaDB admin password
  ## Password is ignored if existingSecret is specified.
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera#setting-the-root-password-on-first-run
  ##
  password: "ObviouslyIChangedThis"
  ## Option to force users to specify a password. That is required for 'helm upgrade' to work properly.
  ## If it is not force, a random password will be generated.
  ##
  forcePassword: false

## Use existing secret (ignores rootUser.password, db.password, and galera.mariabackup.password)
##
# existingSecret:

## Custom db configuration
##
db:
  ## MariaDB username and password
  ## Password is ignored if existingSecret is specified.
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera#creating-a-database-user-on-first-run
  ##
  user: ""
  password: ""
  ## Database to create
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera#creating-a-database-on-first-run
  ##
  name: my_database
  ## Option to force users to specify a password. That is required for 'helm upgrade' to work properly.
  ## If it is not force, a random password will be generated.
  ##
  forcePassword: false

## Galera configuration
##
galera:
  ## Galera cluster name
  ##
  name: galera

  ## Bootstraping options
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera#bootstraping
  ##
  bootstrap:
    ## Node to bootstrap from, you will need to change this parameter in case you want to bootstrap from other node
    ##
    bootstrapFromNode:
    ## Force safe_to_bootstrap in grastate.date file.
    ## This will set safe_to_bootstrap=1 in the node indicated by bootstrapFromNode.
    ##
    forceSafeToBootstrap: false

  ## Credentials to perform backups
  ##
  mariabackup:
    ## MariaBackup username and password
    ## Password is ignored if existingSecret is specified.
    ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera#setting-up-a-multi-master-cluster
    ##
    user: mariabackup
    password: ""
    ## Option to force users to specify a password. That is required for 'helm upgrade' to work properly.
    ## If it is not force, a random password will be generated.
    ##
    forcePassword: false

## LDAP configuration
##
ldap:
  ## Enable LDAP support
  ##
  enabled: false
  uri: ""
  base: ""
  binddn: ""
  bindpw: ""
  bslookup:
  filter:
  map:
  nss_initgroups_ignoreusers: root,nslcd
  scope:
  tls_reqcert:

## TLS configuration
##
tls:
  ## Enable TLS
  ##
  enabled: false
  ## Name of the secret that contains the certificates
  ##
  # certificatesSecret:
  ## Certificate filename
  ##
  # certFilename:
  ## Certificate Key filename
  ##
  # certKeyFilename:
  ## CA Certificate filename
  ##
  # certCAFilename:

## Configure MariaDB with a custom my.cnf file
## ref: https://mysql.com/kb/en/mysql/configuring-mysql-with-mycnf/#example-of-configuration-file
## Alternatively, you can put your my.cnf under the files/ directory
mariadbConfiguration: |-
  [client]
  port=3306
  socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
  plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/plugin
  [mysqld]
  default_storage_engine=InnoDB
  basedir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb
  datadir=/bitnami/mariadb/data
  plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/plugin
  tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp
  socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
  pid_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysqld.pid
  bind_address=0.0.0.0
  ## Character set
  ##
  collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
  init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
  character_set_server=utf8
  ## MyISAM
  ##
  key_buffer_size=32M
  myisam_recover_options=FORCE,BACKUP
  ## Safety
  ##
  skip_host_cache
  skip_name_resolve
  max_allowed_packet=16M
  max_connect_errors=1000000
  sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTI$
  sysdate_is_now=1
  ## Binary Logging
  ##
  log_bin=mysql-bin
  expire_logs_days=14
  # Disabling for performance per http://severalnines.com/blog/9-tips-going-production-galera-cluster-mysql
  sync_binlog=0
  # Required for Galera
  binlog_format=row
  ## Caches and Limits
  ##
  tmp_table_size=32M
  max_heap_table_size=32M
  # Re-enabling as now works with Maria 10.1.2
  query_cache_type=1
  query_cache_limit=4M
  query_cache_size=256M
  max_connections=500
  thread_cache_size=50
  open_files_limit=65535
  table_definition_cache=4096
  table_open_cache=4096
  ## InnoDB
  ##
  innodb=FORCE
  innodb_strict_mode=1
  # Mandatory per https://github.com/codership/documentation/issues/25
  innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
  # Per https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/04/innodb-double-write/
  innodb_doublewrite=1
  innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
  innodb_log_files_in_group=2
  innodb_log_file_size=128M
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
  innodb_file_per_table=1
  # 80% Memory is default reco.
  # Need to re-evaluate when DB size grows
  innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
  innodb_file_format=Barracuda
  ## Logging
  ##
  log_error=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log
  slow_query_log_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log
  log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
  slow_query_log=1
  ## SSL
  ## Use extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts to mount /certs filesystem
  # ssl_ca=/certs/ca.pem
  # ssl_cert=/certs/server-cert.pem
  # ssl_key=/certs/server-key.pem
  [galera]
  wsrep_on=ON
  wsrep_provider=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/lib/libgalera_smm.so
  wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup
  wsrep_slave_threads=4
  wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
  wsrep_cluster_name=galera
  wsrep_sst_auth="root:"
  # Enabled for performance per https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
  # MYISAM REPLICATION SUPPORT #
  wsrep_replicate_myisam=ON
  [mariadb]
  plugin_load_add=auth_pam
  ## Data-at-Rest Encryption
  ## Use extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts to mount /encryption filesystem
  # plugin_load_add=file_key_management
  # file_key_management_filename=/encryption/keyfile.enc
  # file_key_management_filekey=FILE:/encryption/keyfile.key
  # file_key_management_encryption_algorithm=AES_CTR
  # encrypt_binlog=ON
  # encrypt_tmp_files=ON
  ## InnoDB/XtraDB Encryption
  # innodb_encrypt_tables=ON
  # innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables=ON
  # innodb_encrypt_log=ON
  # innodb_encryption_threads=4
  # innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age=1
  ## Aria Encryption
  # aria_encrypt_tables=ON
  # encrypt_tmp_disk_tables=ON
## ConfigMap with MariaDB configuration
## NOTE: This will override mariadbConfiguration
##
# configurationConfigMap:

## Specify dictionary of scripts to be run at first boot
## Alternatively, you can put your scripts under the files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory
##
# initdbScripts:
#   my_init_script.sh: |
#      #!/bin/sh
#      echo "Do something."

## ConfigMap with scripts to be run at first boot
## Note: This will override initdbScripts
##
# initdbScriptsConfigMap:

## MariaDB additional command line flags
## Can be used to specify command line flags, for example:
##
## extraFlags: "--max-connect-errors=1000 --max_connections=155"
##

## Desired number of cluster nodes
##
replicaCount: 3

## updateStrategy for MariaDB Master StatefulSet
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies
##
updateStrategy:
  type: RollingUpdate

## Additional labels for MariaDB Galera pods
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/
##
podLabels: {}

## Additional annotations for MariaDB Galera pods
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/
##
podAnnotations: {}

## Pod affinity preset
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity
## Allowed values: soft, hard
##
podAffinityPreset: ""

## Pod anti-affinity preset
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity
## Allowed values: soft, hard
##
podAntiAffinityPreset: soft

## Node affinity preset
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity
## Allowed values: soft, hard
##
nodeAffinityPreset:
  ## Node affinity type
  ## Node affinity type
  ## Allowed values: soft, hard
  ##
  type: ""
  ## Node label key to match
  ## E.g.
  ## key: "kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name"
  ##
  key: ""
  ## Node label values to match
  ## E.g.
  ## values:
  ##   - e2e-az1
  ##   - e2e-az2
  ##
  values: []

## Affinity for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
## Note: podAffinityPreset, podAntiAffinityPreset, and nodeAffinityPreset will be ignored when it's set
##
affinity: {}

## Node labels for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
##
nodeSelector: {}

## Tolerations for pod assignment. Evaluated as a template.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
tolerations: []

## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
##
persistence:
  ## If true, use a Persistent Volume Claim, If false, use emptyDir
  ##
  enabled: true
  # Enable persistence using an existing PVC
  existingClaim: dbstorage
  # Subdirectory of the volume to mount
  # subPath:
  mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
  ## selector can be used to match an existing PersistentVolume
  ## selector:
  ##   matchLabels:
  ##     app: my-app
  ##
  selector: {}
  ## Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  storageClass: "nfs-storage"
  ## Persistent Volume Claim annotations
  ##
  annotations:
  ## Persistent Volume Access Mode
  ##
  #accessModes:
  #  - ReadWriteOnce
  ## Persistent Volume size
  ##
  #size: 8Gi

## Priority Class Name
#
# priorityClassName: 'priorityClass'

## Additional init containers
##
extraInitContainers: []
# - name: do-something
#   image: bitnami/minideb
#   command: ['do', 'something']

## Additional containers
##
extraContainers: []

## extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts allows you to mount other volumes
## Example Use Cases:
##  mount certificates to enable data-in-transit encryption
##  mount keys for data-at-rest encryption using file plugin
# extraVolumes:
# - name: mariadb-certs
#   secret:
#     defaultMode: 288
#     secretName: mariadb-certs
# - name: mariadb-encryption
#   secret:
#     defaultMode: 288
#     secretName: mariadb-encryption
# extraVolumeMounts:
# - name: mariadb-certs
#   mountPath: /certs
#   readOnly: true
# - name: mariadb-encryption
#   mountPath: /encryption
#   readOnly: true

## MariaDB Galera containers' resource requests and limits
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
##
resources:
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  limits: {}
  #   cpu: 0.5
  #   memory: 256Mi
  requests: {}
  #   cpu: 0.5
  #   memory: 256Mi

## MariaDB Galera containers' liveness and readiness probes
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes
##
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  ## Initializing the database could take some time
  ##
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3
startupProbe:
  enabled: false
  ## Initializing the database could take some time
  ##
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  ## Let's wait 600 seconds by default, it should give enough time in any cluster for mysql to init
  ##
  failureThreshold: 48

## Pod disruption budget configuration
##
podDisruptionBudget:
  ## Specifies whether a Pod disruption budget should be created
  ##
  create: false
  minAvailable: 1
  # maxUnavailable: 1

## Prometheus exporter configuration
##
metrics:
  enabled: false
  ## Bitnami MySQL Prometheus exporter image
  ## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mysqld-exporter/tags/
  ##
  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/mysqld-exporter
    tag: 0.12.1-debian-10-r416
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
    ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
    ##
    # pullSecrets:
    #   - myRegistryKeySecretName
  ## MySQL exporter additional command line flags
  ## Can be used to specify command line flags
  ## E.g.:
  ## extraFlags:
  ##   - --collect.binlog_size
  ##
  extraFlags: []
  ## MySQL Prometheus exporter containers' resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  resources:
    # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
    # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
    # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
    # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
    limits: {}
    #   cpu: 0.5
    #   memory: 256Mi
    requests: {}
    #   cpu: 0.5
    #   memory: 256Mi
  ## MySQL Prometheus exporter service parameters
  ##
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 9104
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "9104"

  ## Prometheus Operator ServiceMonitor configuration
  ##
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: false
    ## Namespace in which Prometheus is running
    ##
    # namespace: monitoring

    ## Interval at which metrics should be scraped.
    ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#endpoint
    ##
    # interval: 10s

    ## Timeout after which the scrape is ended
    ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#endpoint
    ##
    # scrapeTimeout: 10s

    ## ServiceMonitor selector labels
    ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/prometheus-operator#prometheus-configuration
    ##
    selector:
      prometheus: kube-prometheus
    ## RelabelConfigs to apply to samples before scraping
    ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#relabelconfig
    ## Value is evalued as a template
    ##
    relabelings: []

    ## MetricRelabelConfigs to apply to samples before ingestion
    ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md#relabelconfig
    ## Value is evalued as a template
    ##
    metricRelabelings: []
    #  - sourceLabels:
    #      - "__name__"
    #    targetLabel: "__name__"
    #    action: replace
    #    regex: '(.*)'
    #    replacement: 'example_prefix_$1'

  ## Prometheus Operator PrometheusRule configuration
  ##
  prometheusRules:
    enabled: false

    ## Additional labels to add to the PrometheusRule so it is picked up by the operator.
    ## If using the [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) this is the $
    ##
    selector:
      app: prometheus-operator
      release: prometheus

    ## Rules as a map.
    ##
    rules: {}
    #  - alert: MariaDB-Down
    #    annotations:
    #      message: 'MariaDB instance {{ $labels.instance }} is down'
    #      summary: MariaDB instance is down
    #    expr: absent(up{job="mariadb-galera"} == 1)
    #    labels:
    #      severity: warning
    #      service: mariadb-galera
    #    for: 5m
```

**EDIT**
adding log file from container initialization:

```
mariadb 13:59:39.44
mariadb 13:59:39.44 Welcome to the Bitnami mariadb-galera container
mariadb 13:59:39.45 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera
mariadb 13:59:39.45 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera/issues
mariadb 13:59:39.46
mariadb 13:59:39.47 INFO  ==> ** Starting MariaDB setup **
mariadb 13:59:40.30 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mariadb 13:59:40.41 DEBUG ==> Set Galera cluster address to gcomm://
mariadb 13:59:40.42 INFO  ==> Initializing mariadb database
mariadb 13:59:40.43 DEBUG ==> Ensuring expected directories/files exist
mariadb 13:59:40.46 WARN  ==> The mariadb configuration file '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf' is not writable or does not exist. Configurations based on environment variables will not be applied for this file.
mariadb 13:59:40.49 DEBUG ==> Cleaning data directory to ensure successfully initialization
Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/bitnami/mariadb/data' ...
```

Unfortunately that is it. The container is now in a "CrashLoopBackOff" state. It restarted 7 times already and will not finish. I can see on my NFS server the "data" directory is created and it contains 2 files, "aria_log_control" and "mysql-bin.index". The my.cnf looks like being owned by root but as far as I could find in the documentation the container is a non-root container so the file would not be writable. But it is definitely there. I checked that several times.
If I describe the pod I get the error message mentioned above "Readiness probe failed".

**END EDIT**

**EDIT 2**
here are the details on the readiness, liveness probe.

```
## MariaDB Galera containers' liveness and readiness probes
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes
##
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  ## Initializing the database could take some time
  ##
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3
startupProbe:
  enabled: false
  ## Initializing the database could take some time
  ##
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  ## Let's wait 600 seconds by default, it should give enough time in any cluster for mysql to init
  ##
  failureThreshold: 48
```

**END EDIT**

**EDIT 3**
I have no choice but to respond to my original post. I would otherwise exceed the character limit of stackoverflow.
**End EDIT**

I would be grateful for any help or hint you can provide to get the cluster up and running.

realshadow

---

So I followed your advise @WytrzymałyWiktor and disabled the readiness and liveness probes. That way all 3 instances are spun up right away. The problem is they are not communicating among each other. Logs from the
So despite having the pods running they are not working and communicating among each other.

Comment: Hello @realShadow. Could you please check the logs of the failed Pod and share them with us by editing your question?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor thanks for your feedback. I added the log information. Grateful for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Hi @realShadow. Thanks for the output. Could you also share the exact configuration of the `ReadinessProbe`?

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor of course. It is already mentioned in the *values.yaml* file but I also posted in my edit #2.

Comment: Hi @realShadow. Thanks for the outputs but we need to dig deeper. Try to disable liveness and readiness probes and see if mysqld will start running. After that, try to again get some new logs with `kubectl logs -f --tail=20 <mariadb-galera>`

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Thanks for your response. I will try that and report back as soon as I have a chance to get that tested.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor thanks for your feedback. Please find the details of the logs in my post below. I had to do it that way as otherwise the character limit would have been exceeded.

Comment: Thanks @realShadow. Let's focus on one problem at the time and not mix up multiple topics in one question as it would be hard to follow by the rest of the community. I'm going to post an answer addressing your initial issue with the Kubernetes Probes so we could close that topic. Regarding the mariadb communication issue it would be better if you describe it in a separate question providing the most recent and necessary info. It will make it way easier for the rest of the community to help you out with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we already investigated there was an issue with your Probes configuration. Most likely their parameters were not adjusted correctly and so the Pod could not start as it was failing the Readiness check.

In order to make the Pod start properly you can either disable them or adjust your [probe's configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes) in order to meet you requirements:

> Probes have a number of fields that you can use to more precisely
> control the behavior of liveness and readiness checks:
>
> - `initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated. Defaults to
>   0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.
> - `periodSeconds`: How often (in seconds) to perform the probe. Default to 10 seconds. Minimum value is 1.
> - `timeoutSeconds`: Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second. Minimum value is 1.
> - `successThreshold`: Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be considered successful after having failed. Defaults to 1. Must be 1
>   for liveness. Minimum value is 1.
> - `failureThreshold`: When a probe fails, Kubernetes will try failureThreshold times before giving up. Giving up in case of liveness
>   probe means restarting the container. In case of readiness probe the
>   Pod will be marked Unready. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1.

Below you will find some useful sources that will share some more light on that topic:

- [Kubernetes best practices: Setting up health checks with readiness and liveness probes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes)
- [Fantastic Probes And How To Configure Them — A Kubernetes Story](https://medium.com/swlh/fantastic-probes-and-how-to-configure-them-fef7e030bd2f)

Also, the error you saw:

```
The mariadb configuration file '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf' is not writable or does not exist. Configurations based on environment variables will not be applied for this file.
```

means that the chart deploys a ConfigMap and mounts it by defoult, so it is not readable/writable by the container image which is perfectly fine and should not worry you.

Comment: Hello @realShadow. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: sorry. I was trying to implement your suggestion and it took me some time. Unfortunately the startup of the pods or the delays with which the probes are executed are not the issue. I changed livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds: to 180 and 240 without success. The same for the readiness probe. I added additional time to the timeoutseconds to allow a little more time for the test. Without success. I still get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as I found out, was related to how the NFS server was accessed. I used the NFS provisioner for Kubernetes [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/tree/master/deploy). That provisioner runs as root and that was the issue with the bitnami helm chart. In the securityContext of the chart the user and group are 1001:1001 meaning it does not run as root. My NFS server was also setup with root access. first I needed to change my NFS server share:

```
/path/to/share *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,insecure,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
```

The important parts are the `anonuid` and `anongid` above. Then I created subfolders for each DB node that I intend to run. These sub-folders are the mountpoints in the pv later. I changed the owner of the whole share with `chown 1001:1001 -R /path/to/share`. That was it for the NFS server.

Next I created 3 pvs on the kubernetes cluster, one for each DB node.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: db-persistent-storage-0
  labels:
    app: mariadb-galera-cluster
  namespace: database
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  mountOptions:
    - nolock
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: SERVERIP
    path: /path/to/share/subfolder1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: db-persistent-storage-1
  labels:
    app: mariadb-galera-cluster
  namespace: database
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  mountOptions:
    - nolock
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: SERVERIP
    path: /path/to/share/subfolder2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: db-persistent-storage-2
  labels:
    app: mariadb-galera-cluster
  namespace: database
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  mountOptions:
    - nolock
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: SERVERIP
    path: /path/to/share/subfolder3
```

Make sure you replace your `SERVERIP` and `/path/to/share` to reflect your own setup. Once created in the cluster, I was able to run the bitnami chart successfully. I still got the error message mentioned in my original post above

```
Readiness probe failed: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' 
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

but that must have been an issue with the timeouts I did not change. All 3 pods are up and running now and seem to work fine.
If you follow these instructions make sure in the `values.yaml` that you adjust the persistent volume settings to reflect the `label` section that is mentioned in the PV above. Otherwise the helm chart won't pick up these existing volumes and not create the nodes. For the examples above that section should look like:

```
persistence:
  ## If true, use a Persistent Volume Claim, If false, use emptyDir
  ##
  enabled: true
  ## selector can be used to match an existing PersistentVolume
  ##
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mariadb-galera-cluster
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  ## Persistent Volume size
  ##
  size: 1Gi
```

Thanks for all your help.